# How can I dynamically infer types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference, mapped-types

There is a way where types can be inferred dynamically, similarly to a union type?

What I'm trying to do is register multiple elements from different parts of the code with a method like `registerElement(...)` but I cannot figure out how to infer these new types with typescript, and end up with errors like `Type '"pack"' is not assignable to type '"common"'`.

In the correct behaviour I expect when a new element is registered, in the example `"pack"`, it gets available for use, and since I don't know how many elements will have, and they can be added or removed with new code I'm not considering hard coded types like:

```
type ElementTypes = Common | Pack | ...N
```

> I know ts infering types happens on compile-time and not on runtime and the example below does not work.

```
interface BaseElement<T, C> {
    name: T,
    nested: C[]
}

interface Common extends BaseElement<'common', string> {}

const common: Common = {
    name: 'common',
    nested: []
}

const myElements = {common}

type ElementTypes = keyof typeof myElements

const foo: ElementTypes = 'common'; // Ok.

// Assign a new element
interface Pack extends BaseElement<'pack', Common> {}

const pack: Pack = {
    name: 'pack',
    nested: []
}

Object.assign(myElements, {pack});
const bar: ElementTypes = 'pack'; // Not working.
```

Comment: You have not described how the function `registerElement` is supposed to be used (or do you mean `document.registerElement()` ?), even though it seems to be a vital part in this problem.

Comment: If you can describe how your functionality would work in plain JavaScript, we could surely find a solution for how to type it properly.

Comment: TS can't model the mutation of type definitions (e.g., `ElementTypes` is `X | Y` now and `X | Y | Z` later in the code), and it can only model the mutation of the the types of values in a very limited way (e.g., `foo`'s type is `{x: string}` now and `{x: string, y: string}` later), so I think what you want is either impossible or not worth the trouble.

Comment: @TobiasS. `registerElement()` is not a real method, it is just a hypothetical method to symbolize it is supposed to register a new Element, but the so-called implementation is described in the example as `Object.assign` in a simple manner.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, indeed, but as far as I know some type definitions, as interfaces can be merged, and that's my question, if there's a way to create a reusable method/class/something where I can assign new elements, as described on the example as `ElementTypes`, inferring the registered element types to a "high order type"

Comment: @jcalz It is something like adsy answered below, as a "Plugin Architecture" type of pattern, I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> I know ts infering types happens on compile-time and not on runtime and the example below does not work.

This is also the exact reason why what you are asking is impossible and a misunderstanding of TS.

> and since I don't know how many elements will have, and they can be added or removed with new code I'm not considering hard coded types like:

If the total set of possible string literals is known, you absolutely do need a union of all those types. That is not something to be avoided, it is the correct way of modeling the problem. That at runtime the object/array possibly only contains a subset of those is not relevant, since the type system only cares about *what is possible to be in there* and can't possibly know what is in there at a given time since it's not in the runtime. You might ask how then can you use one of these things as its own type. Basically, that's with runtime code. See [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

If any string whatsoever can be added at runtime, for example, by user input, then you can't strongly type the array/object contents to that level of granularity. Instead, you'd simply use `string`.

Comment: So, it's basically an impossible problem to solve with infer types the best approach would be set as string?

Comment: If the user can just input a random string in a textfield or something then yes that's correct. Otherwise, you'd be trying to type for every known string in the universe :D. If the set of strings is limited though, then that'd be different.

Comment: It's supposed to be a developer use case, where the dev can `registerElement` as new features are implemented, without the need to update the union type every new element we develop. Like the example where I set the `Common` element and posteriorly if I would like to add `Pack` it would be possible with `registerElement` and the auto-complete are supposed to work properly.

Comment: Right, thats useful and important context. For this you will want interface merging. This is basically a "plugin" system.

Comment: In this system, each time a dev uses `register element`, they will also define an interface with the same name as one in your base types. Since TS merges interfaces even across files into one (note, `interface`, not `type`), you can use this to build such a system. This is a bit fiddly as it inevitably means it doesn't happen magically. You'll need to give the devs guidance on how to expand the base TS types. But this is pretty common with this type of pattern.

Comment: https://code.lol/post/programming/plugin-architecture/ This is an example of this

Comment: What the name of this pattern?

Comment: I would google around "ts plugin type system" but the underlying mechanism is the same every time -- Declaration merging. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks for this information, it really gave me some clarification.